# Interstitial Ad not getting loaded in device (using google play services)

Tags: android, admob

Did anyone face similar error?

Getting Error: SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]

SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/NotificationPermissions.db) -

Followed all steps as per below link:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced

Please see log below:

06-01 16:11:43.613: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(19506): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
06-01 16:11:43.643: D/LOG_TAG(19506): Interstitial ad was not ready to be shown.
06-01 16:11:43.673: D/dalvikvm(19506): GC_CONCURRENT freed 730K, 16% free 12073K/14279K, paused 6ms+6ms, total 63ms
06-01 16:11:43.724: I/brcm-gr(19506): [gralloc_lock]: new usage 0x933
06-01 16:11:43.764: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(19506): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
06-01 16:11:43.774: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(19506): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
06-01 16:11:43.804: D/MainGamePanel(19506): Surface is being destroyed
06-01 16:11:43.804: D/Surface Destroyed(19506): Thread was shut down cleanly
06-01 16:11:43.804: W/SurfaceView(19506): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=true left=false top=false
06-01 16:11:43.814: W/SurfaceView(19506): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=false surfaceChanged=false realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
06-01 16:11:43.824: E/SpannableStringBuilder(19506): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-01 16:11:43.824: E/SpannableStringBuilder(19506): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-01 16:11:43.844: W/SurfaceView(19506): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=false surfaceChanged=false realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
06-01 16:12:07.036: W/Ads(19506): Timed out waiting for ad response.
06-01 16:12:07.036: W/Ads(19506): Timed out waiting for ad response.
06-01 16:12:07.086: E/SQLiteLog(19506): (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]
06-01 16:12:07.086: E/SQLiteLog(19506): (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/NotificationPermissions.db) - 
06-01 16:12:07.086: D/WebKit(19506): ERROR: 
06-01 16:12:07.086: D/WebKit(19506): SQLite database failed to load from /NotificationPermissions.db
06-01 16:12:07.086: D/WebKit(19506): Cause - unable to open database file
06-01 16:12:07.086: D/WebKit(19506): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
06-01 16:12:07.096: E/SQLiteLog(19506): (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]
06-01 16:12:07.096: E/SQLiteLog(19506): (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/NotificationPermissions.db) - 
06-01 16:12:07.096: D/WebKit(19506): ERROR: 
06-01 16:12:07.096: D/WebKit(19506): SQLite database failed to load from /NotificationPermissions.db
06-01 16:12:07.096: D/WebKit(19506): Cause - unable to open database file
06-01 16:12:07.106: D/WebKit(19506): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
06-01 16:12:07.106: W/Ads(19506): Failed to load ad: 2
06-01 16:12:07.106: W/Ads(19506): Failed to load ad: 2

Comment: Can you post your log here so we can see what the exact resaon is for that eroor